# Howto exclude jpeg-names from regexp replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, documentation

I'm using a search-function for a documentation site which upon selection of search hit shows page with text highlighted (just as a pdf-reader or netbeans would do).

To achive the highlight i use javascript with:

```
function searchHighlight(searchTxt) {
  var target = $('#page').html();
  var re = new RegExp(searchTxt, 'gi');
  target = target.replace(
    re,
    '<span class="high">' + searchTxt + '</span>'
  );
  $('#page').html(target);
}
```

**Problem / Question:**

Since page incudes images with filenames based on md5, some searches messes up the image src.

Searching on "1000" will distort the

```
<img src="53451000abababababa---.jpg"
```

to

```
<img src="5334<span class="hl">1000</span>abababab--.jpg">
```

Is it possible to solve this with regexp, somehow excluding anything anjcent to ".jpg"?

Or would it be possible to, before highligting replace the images with placeholders, and after replace revert back to src?

Example:

- replace all <img *> with {{I-01}}, {{I-02}} etc and keep the real src in a var.
- Do the replace above.
- Revert back from {{I-01}} to the <img src=".."/>

DOM-manipulation is of course an option, but I figure this could be done with regexp somehow, however, my regexp skills are lacking badly.

**UPDATE**
This code works for me now:

```
function searchHighlight(searchTxt) {    
var stack = new Array();
var stackPtr = 0;
var target = $('#page').html();
//pre
target = target.replace(/<img.+?>/gi,function(match) {
  stack[stackPtr] = match;
  return '{{im' + (stackPtr++) + '}}';
});
//replace
var re = new RegExp(searchTxt, 'gi');
target = target.replace(re,'<span class="high">' + searchTxt + '</span>');
//post
stackPtr = 0;
target = target.replace(/{{im.+?}}/gi,function(match) {
    return stack[stackPtr++];
});
$('#page').html(target);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you figure out something to solve this but then you will have some other problem because your approach is not good. Don't try to understand HTML with regex.

Comment: @ankitbug94, I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Can you include `html` of `#page` element at Question?

Comment: `searchTxt` is user input?

Comment: @Fallenhero, yes. think PDF-reader with searchbox and hitlist. Upon click on hit, page is shown and highlight-function runs.

Comment: what's your plan for `searchTxt=img` or `>` etc. that will completely break your HTML

Comment: The plan is fine. It's an intranet application. </> can be forbidden. Page consists of <hN>, <p>, some tables and images. (and the actual search is performed towards a page stripped from tags, so no hit will show on "img" as argument.)

Comment: http://codepen.io/tomjoad2000/pen/oYMvyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create an array of all possible valid search terms. Set the terms as `.textContent` of `<span>` elements within `#page` parent element.

At `searchHighlight` function check if `searchTxt` matches an element within array. If `searchTxt` matches an element of array, select `span` element using index of matched array element, toggle `"high"` `.className` at matched `#page span` element, else notify user that `searchTxt`  does not match any valid search terms.

```js
$(function() {
  var words = [];
  var input = $("input[type=text]");
  var button = $("input[type=button][value=Search]");
  var reset = $("input[type=button][value=Reset]");
  var label = $("label");
  var page = $("#page");
  var contents = $("h1, p", page).contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && /\w+/.test(this.nodeValue)
    }).map(function(i, text) {
      var span = text.nodeValue.split(/\s/).filter(Boolean)
        .map(function(word, index) {
          words.push(word);
          return "<span>" + word + "</span> "
        });
      $(text.parentElement).find(text).replaceWith(span);
    })
  var spans = $("span", page);
  button.on("click", function(event) {
    spans.removeClass("high");
    label.html("");
    if (input.val().length && /\w+/.test(input.val())) {
      var terms = input.val().match(/\w+/g);
      var indexes = $.map(terms, function(term) {
        var search = $.map(words, function(word, index) {
          return word.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 && index
        }).filter(Boolean);
        return search
      });
      if (indexes.length) {
        $.each(indexes, function(_, index) {
          spans.eq(index).addClass("high")
        })
      } else {
        label.html("Search term <em>" + input.val() + "</em> not found.");
      }
    }
  });
  reset.on("click", function(event) {
    spans.removeClass("high");
    input.val("");
    label.html("");
  })
})
```

```css
.high {
  background-color: #caf;
}
label em {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Search" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" />
<label></label>
<div id="page" style="max-width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;">
  <h1 style="margin:0px;">test of replace</h1>
  <p>After Luke comes to Dagobah, Yoda initially withholds his true identity. He’s trying to get a sense of who Luke is as a person; Yoda understands that there’s a lot at risk in training Luke to be a Jedi, especially considering what happened with his
    father.
    <img style="float:right;" width="200" src="http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2013/11/04-400x225.jpg">And Yoda is not impressed — Luke is impatient and selfish. With “Adventure. Excitement. A Jedi craves not these things,” the Jedi Master makes clear that Luke must understand the significance and meaning of the journey he thinks he wants to make.
    It’s an important lesson for Luke and for audiences, because when Luke faces Vader at the film’s climax, we see the stakes involved in the life of a Jedi</p>
  <p>Now Yoda-search works, however a search on "sites" will break the image-link. (Yes, I know this implementation isn't perfect but I'm dealing with reality)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's however a doc-site with approx 1000 pages. Valid search terms would be to broad.

Comment: What do you mean by "too broad"? Each word, or the word that you determine to be search terms can be placed within `<span>` element within `#page` element. You are already doing the same at `searchHighlight` function. The approach described eliminates need to modify `html`, other than to toggle `.className` of element. The number of pages should not matter.

Comment: From my perspective, I really can't see how this would solve anything. Let's say "1000" should be a valid search term, then it would still break the img-src above.

Comment: No, it would not, as `RegExp` would not be used to change any `html`. Toggle `"high"` `.className` of the  `<span>` elements where `.textContent` contains `"1000"`. `<img>` elements, nor any other omitted elements, would not be a part of the process.