# Extracting a DOM fragment of inline elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking to wrap a DOM fragment of inine elements with another inline element. The fragment may start/end at any point within an element(s). So given the following snippet:

```
<p>The quick <b>br[own fox <i>jumps ov]er</i></b> the lazy dog.</p>
```

How do I extract everything between the square brackets retaining the various tags? Each character in the example will be wrapped in a span (not included here for clarity) so I'm not looking at breaking text nodes etc. The spans are available as a nodeList/array. I can see how to get there with the example above but am struggling to come up with a robust solution that will work regardless of the fragment/level of nesting involved.

My brain is beginning to melt so *any* help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post what you already have.

Comment: What do you mean by "retaining the various tags?"?

Comment: *"Each character in the example will be wrapped in a span"*: like `<span>b</span><span>r</span><span>o</span><span>w</span><span>n</span>`? Why would you do that???

Comment: @guest271314 retaining the `<b>` and `<i>` tags around the relevant parts, i.e. `<b>own fox...`.

Comment: @trincot it's part of a highlighting app, the spans being the target of the various events. I've had to do it this way, I won't go into why.

Comment: What is the input by which you decide which part has to be extracted? In the example, do you have as a given `'own fox jumps ov'`, or are you saying the square brackets actually appear in the HTML snippet?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't clear at all. The spans to be extracted will have a colour associated via a data attribute, e.g. `data-hl="yellow"`. The other spans will share the same attribute but will be valueless.

Comment: See [Howto exclude jpeg-names from regexp replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057212/howto-exclude-jpeg-names-from-regexp-replace/)