# How to robustly underline a letter in a HTML snippet via the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm building a keyboard access library for my web app. To hint at what keys should be pressed i want to underline the key in links. E.g.

> **O**rders   ---  **I**nvoices   ---    Ope**n** Incidents

For pure text snippets this is easy (jQuery used here):

```
part.html(part.html().replace(new RegExp(key, 'i'), '<u>$&</u>'));
```

But this breaks horribly if there is any html markup inside `part`. Is there an elegant way to just update text nodes and never markup?

Clarification: My use case is hundreds of nested templates server side generating the HTML. Currently `accesskey` attributes are added by hand. Resulting in something like `<a href="angebote.html" accesskey="t"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-podcast"></i>Ange<b>bote</b></a>`. A Javascript Front-End Script then among other things adds keybindings and trying to underline the bound keys.

Comment: You might want to parse the nodes with the XML parser or an XPath expression to filter text nodes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057212/howto-exclude-jpeg-names-from-regexp-replace/41057702#41057702

Comment: `"I"` would also match `"I"` in "Incidents"

Comment: Can you include `html` that you are using at Question?

Comment: @guest271314, without the `g` modifier, a `replace()` will only match the first occurrence.

Comment: @trincot Without `html` and issue with current `html`, viewers are left to create `html` which may not reflect `html` at inquiry. The simplest solution would be to adjust `html` to accommodate requirement, use `css` to style elements having specific letter.

Comment: @guest271314, maybe you were addressing the OP? I was just replying to your statement that *`"I"` would also match `"I"` in "Incidents"*.

Comment: @trincot Without viewing `html` in conjunction with `javascript` which reproduces issue, we would only be speculating as to what issue is. One solution would be to utilize `html` and `css` instead of `javascript`, to avoid  issues.

Comment: @guest271314, maybe you were addressing the OP (again)? I was just replying to your statement that "I" would also match "I" in "Incidents", not speculating about the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are speculating about an issue; as no issue has been produced or reproduced given content of Question. There is no "the issue" which can presently be clearly indicated within text of Question.

Answer (score 2):

To get to the text nodes only, and make the replacement there, you could use a tree walker. I would also create a function that isolates the found letter in a `span` element and returns that. Then you can use jQuery (or whatever methods) to decorate that element as you wish:

```js
function getLetter(elem, letter){
    if (elem.get) elem = elem.get(0); // remove jQuery wrapper
    var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(elem, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, null),
        $node, text, pos, $span;
    letter = letter.toLowerCase();
    while ($node = $(nodes.nextNode())) {
        text = $node.text();
        pos = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(letter);
        if (pos > -1) {
            $span = $('<span>').text(text[pos]);
            $node.replaceWith( // separate the letter from the other text
                text.substr(0, pos),
                $span,
                text.substr(pos+1)
            );
            return $span; // return the element that just has that one letter
        }
    }
}

getLetter($('#orders'), 'o').addClass('underline');
getLetter($('#invoices'), 'i').addClass('underline');
getLetter($('#incidents'), 'n').addClass('underline');
```

```css
.underline { text-decoration: underline }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Some mix of HTML:</h3>
<div id="orders">
    <span style="color: purple">Order<i>(s)</i></span>
</div>
<div id="invoices">
    <ul><li><b>!!</b>Invoices <i>(urgent)</i></li></ul>
</div>
<div id="incidents">
    <table style="border: 1px solid"><tr><td>Open</td><td>incidents</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

### Explanation of the Function

The function takes two arguments:

- `elem`: the container element which has the text that needs to be searched. This element may or may not have nested HTML mark up.
- `letter`: the letter to identify within that element: only the first occurrence of that letter will play a role.

The function returns:

- `undefined` when there is no match, i.e. the provided letter does not occur in any text contained by the provided element.
- A new `span` element that the function has created: it will contain the letter that was found. The remaining text is put in separate text nodes before and after that new element.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/n2Kd6jOuV3NNBHOpTVjH?p=preview, `getLetter($('.Orders'), 'n').addClass('underline')` produces issue at `while` loop

Comment: @guest271314, there is no issue with the `while` loop: if you inspect the resulting HTML, the `span` elements are added correctly. Maybe you feel that it should apply it to different words, but you need of course to provide a selector that will identify the text container where the *first* occurrence of the letter will be targeted. Just providing `div` for all three replacements will not produce the desired result. See corrected version: http://plnkr.co/edit/VnRUxMnVGrKHtUQkSYEP?p=preview

Comment: An infinite loop occurred at plnkr using `getLetter($('.Orders'), 'n').addClass('underline')` without guidance as to how to use the function.  It is your Answer; you should be aware best how to detail expected usage, and how not to use function. If solution is to adjust `html`, why use `javascript` at all?  `html` and `css` can be used to prevent issues described at OP, for which we currently do not have a reproducible example of either `html` or issue. plnkr appears to return expected result.

Comment: I don't see any infinite loop occurring. Please demonstrate such a claim.

Comment: Substitute `getLetter($('.Orders'), 'n').addClass('underline')` for ``getLetter($('div'), 'n').addClass('underline')`` at last line at version 1 of http://plnkr.co/edit/n2Kd6jOuV3NNBHOpTVjH?p=preview

Comment: Which browser are you using? I cannot reproduce any infinite looping with this on FireFox nor on Chrome. When I `console.log('done')` at the end, it appears.

Comment: chromium 57. Had to use `Task Manager` to end processes at tab at several occasions http://plnkr.co/edit/n2Kd6jOuV3NNBHOpTVjH?p=preview

Comment: Well that just means that chromium 57 is buggy on the [`nextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/nextNode) method: that should *never* result in an infinite loop: it would make that method useless. As you can see in the code, as long as `pos === -1` there is nothing extra-ordinary happening in that loop, and when it enters the `if` block, the loop is ended.

Comment: _"just means"_?

Comment: I am running on Chrome 58 -- no problem.

Comment: Ok. Produced infinite loop using `.Orders` as selector at chromium 57.

Comment: Note also extra closing `</span>` tag at `<span style="color: purple">Order<i>(s)</i></span></span>` at `html` at Answer.

Comment: That does not matter: browsers will "heal" bad HTML, which you can see when you inspect the DOM after it has been loaded. The original HTML plays no role any more once the DOM is built from it (I have removed the dangling closing tag from my answer's sample).

Comment: _"The original HTML plays no role any more once the DOM is built from it."_ ? That is incorrect. `html` can be invalid. And can effect `javascript` queries to the `DOM`. For example, duplicate `id`s in `document`.

Comment: Indeed, HTML can be invalid, but the DOM will still be correct. What I mean is: if this is why you think the code gets into an infinite loop on your setup, then I want to say: no, that cannot be the reason. And although `id` must be unique according to specs, DOM can deal with that, and will just return all matches when you do `document.querySelectorAll('#someid')`. It will not lead to an infinite loop for a tree walker's `nextNode` method according to its definition.

Comment: You cannot substantiate "why you think". You cannot possibly gather what this user thinks. The extra closing tag was noticed when again reproducing the infinite loop demonstrated at version 2 of linked plnkr. Only conveyed that the infinite loop occurs at chromium 57. You are best suited to address or not address your code implementation.

Comment: I wrote ***"if this is..."***: please don't twist my words. I will stop here, because you seem to be very argumentative. I have better things to do.

Comment: That is a good idea. "if this is..." is presumptive. Do not "twist" any words. That is what you typed. You presumed the extra `</span>` tag was related to infinite loop, which it was not. It  was a gesture, which you evidently did not get as such. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For single letters it should be trivial with the [range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents), since they won't be split over multiple nested nodes.

```
let range = document.createRange();
let div = document.createElement("div")
div.textContent = "Orders --- Invoices --- Open Incidents"
let textNode = div.firstChild

let underline = document.createElement("u")

range.setStart(textNode, 0);
range.setEnd(textNode, 1);
range.surroundContents(underline);
console.log(div.outerHTML)
// <div><u>O</u>rders --- Invoices --- Open Incidents</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'),function(el){  
     el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML.replace(el.getAttribute('acceskey'), 
     '<u>'+el.getAttribute('acceskey')+'</u>')  
 })
```

Try it here: [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rryok7wr/)

Comment: The question was how to do it when the targetted element has HTML markup. Try adding `<i>` inside your second `a` element before the first `i`: https://jsfiddle.net/rryok7wr/1/