# Scan DOM for a String in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a simple way to traverse a DOM (or element) for a given string in Angularjs. If the given string is found, I'd like to bold it's text. I feel I'm overthinking this already since I haven't come up with a solution yet.

For example

Searching for **Dog** should return 4 results

```
<section id="container">
  <div>
    <h2>Dogs are great</h2>
    <p>They are the best. Everyone should have a dog</p>
    <div>
      <p>Cat owners are just confused dog owners</p>
      <p>What's your doggos name?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
$scope.search = function(word){
    var entireDom = // Get the entire innerText of the <section>
    if(entireDom.match(word) {
      // Wrap the string in <strong> tags & update the DOM somehow?
      // This function should probably be case insensitive
    }
}
<script>
```

Any ideas or tips would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See [Howto exclude jpeg-names from regexp replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41057212/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies that logic indiscriminately to the entire innerHTML of the body of a document:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(dog)/gi, '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

I would not do this on nodes with children though. What happens if I search for “div”. If you want more control over which nodes, you can do that replace regex on the innerHTML specific nodes only, simple example:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"))
  .forEach(f => {
    if(f.children.length === 0) f.innerHTML = f.innerHTML.replace(/(dog)/gi, '<strong>$1</strong>')
  });
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/kbLvdvh9/

This does alter the DOM. It might be easier to add a span with a class to those nodes so you can turn the highlight off when searching for a new word or something.

Comment: Thanks Jorg. This is a perfect solution. Could you advise how to pass a variable as the first argument in  `replace()` function? It's tricky with the slashes & `gi` involved

Comment: You’ll need to use the Regexp class, you’ll find documentation and answers on that elsewhere.